# What is conductivity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrostatics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-spin

I read that if we have spin $\frac{1}{2}$-particle, where a magetic force acts on, then the force is given by a drift speed times a conductivity. This conductivity is determined to be $\frac{kT}{D}$, where $D$ is the diffusion coefficient. Now, I was wondering which conductivity is meant in that case?

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: Are you asking which of [these definitions of conductivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductivity) is relevant?

Comment: yes, exactly....